# What's the "proper" way to do a sticky top nav in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Affix and `<body data-spy="scroll" ...` but it's rather wonky. When I scroll down to the content, the nav sticks at the top, but the content jumps up behind it, due to this CSS:

```
nav.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Obviously, when the nav becomes `position: fixed`, it's removed from the flow and so the content jumps up behind it. How do I fix this so the content doesn't do that?

(will post code if people request it, it's kind of a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little futzing around, I came up with this. Happy to hear any better solutions, though! This seems silly to have to do this, surprised Bootstrap doesn't handle this automatically.

```
  $('nav').on('affixed.bs.affix affixed-top.bs.affix', function(e) {
    var $nav = $(e.target);

    if ($nav.hasClass('navbar')) {
      if (e.type === 'affixed') {
        $('body').css('padding-top', $nav.height());
      } else {
        $('body').css('padding-top', '0');
      }
    }
  });
```